# blogs in sharepoint req . . 

Tags: 2007

I want to create a blog kind of mechanism in sharepoint .
How is this possible in sp ?
i want to use out of box features , so what kind of template can i use . .
what does a blog template do ?

Answer (score 2):

The blog template provided with WSS should provide basic blogging capability that supports comments. Depends on how complex you want your blog, but create a blog subsite and see how it suits you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your szenario you might consider to use CKS:EBE 
http://cks.codeplex.com/releases/view/28520

Answer (score 0):

You can create blog site by using Blog as a temlpate.
This will let you to create blog by using this site and users of this site can comment on your blog.

i think it should fullfill your requirement.